# How can I traverse all tables for a common column and delete all records with a match using Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an oracle SQL statement that gets all the tables with a certain column that appears in multiple tables.

```
select owner, table_name from all_tab_columns 
where column_name = 'DOCUMENT_ID' 
order by table_name;
```

Now, I want to add delete functionality that will delete all records in all tables where DOCUMENT_ID = 1

I don't want to do this one table at a time as there are many, close to 30.

UPDATE:  In my comment, what if there's an FOREIGN KEY ID - for example, and the record I'm about to delete, has a child record

Let's take for example as we loop the records, as indicated in the great solution below.

Let's say that DOCTYPE_ID appears in the record where **document_id** = 1 appears. **DOCTYPE_ID** = 123. So, I'll need to search all other tables or the table where **DOCTYPE_ID** = 123 and delete all those rows as well.

There are only 31 tables in the DB and that's never going to change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` to generate the dynamic DML needed:

```
BEGIN
  FOR rec_table IN (SELECT owner,table_name
                      FROM all_tab_columns
                     WHERE column_name = 'DOCUMENT_ID')
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DELETE FROM "'||rec_table.owner||'"."'||rec_table.table_name||'" WHERE document_id = 1';
    COMMIT;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Keep in mind that you'd obviously need delete permission on all these tables for this to work. I would suggest also building in some kind of filter on the `OWNER` to prevent hitting tables you don't intend.

**UPDATE**:

Your question was updated to reflect the need to follow foreign key relationships to delete rows from child tables. If that's what this is about, you don't need to write any special code. Simply define your foreign keys with the `ON DELETE CASCADE` option and if the parent is deleted, the children with foreign keys defined this way will be automatically deleted. This isn't something you should have to code yourself.

Comment: There's another issue, what if I have another ID, and it can be anything, what if that ID's a a foreign key, and I need to delete the child records where the two ID's match... let me update my question.... to show

Comment: @PeterTheAngularDude - Updated my answer

Comment: Of course... just like MS SQL Server - You got my vote